# Activity transition not working propery

Tags: android, animation, transition

I want to show activity transition effect like link http://blog.stylingandroid.com/material-part-8/ mean after tap on listview item activity open from middle and increase slowly with up and down side.

I did a following code but its showing other transition effect.Its not working like expected as per given in above link.

In FirstActivty.java

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

                String transitionName = getString(R.string.transition);

                ActivityOptionsCompat transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(FirstActivity.this, view, transitionName);
                ActivityCompat.startActivity(FirstActivity.this, intent, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
            }
        });
```

in SecondActivity.java

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

           RelativeLayout rootElement = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);

            //Set Transition
           ViewCompat.setTransitionName(rootElement,getString(R.string.transition));
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        int id = menuItem.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {

            //Finish Transition
            ActivityCompat.finishAfterTransition(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
```